# How to split one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table:

```
column1
--------
05 MODE-PARTNER      MIC Z(7)9
08 MODE-FLERS01      MIC X
```

Output:

```
column1    column2        column3
----------------------------------
05         MODE-PARTNER   MIC Z(7)9
08         MODE-FLERS01   MIC X
```

I have used `patindex` and `charindex` but the results are not coming correct.
please help me out with the SQL query.

My query:

```
select
    column4
    , LEFT(column4, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', column4 )) AS column1 
    , LTRIM(RIGHT(column4, LEN(column4) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', column4 ))) As column2
    , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)>0 THEN ltrim(SUBSTRING(column4,1,CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)-1)) ELSE column4 END column2_new
    , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)>0 THEN ltrim(SUBSTRING(column4,CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)-0,len(column4))) ELSE NULL END AS column3
from table1
where column4 IN ('05 MODE-PARTNER MIC Z(7)9','08 MODE-FLERS01 MIC X')
```

Comment: select column4
,LEFT(column4, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', column4 )) AS column1
,LTRIM(RIGHT(column4, LEN(column4) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', column4 ))) As column2,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)>0 
         THEN ltrim(SUBSTRING(column4,1,CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)-1)) 
         ELSE column4 END column2_new,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)>0 
         THEN ltrim(SUBSTRING(column4,CHARINDEX('PIC',column4)-0,len(column4)))  
         ELSE NULL END AS column3
from table1 where column4 IN ('05         MODE-PARTNER   MIC Z(7)9','08         MODE-FLERS01   MIC X')

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 3):

[`ParseName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an option provided your patterns are consistent

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([column1] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('05 MODE-PARTNER MIC Z(7)9')
,('08 MODE-FLERS01 MIC X')


Select column1 = parsename(S,4)
      ,column2 = parsename(S,3)
      ,column3 = concat(parsename(S,2),' ',parsename(S,1))
 from @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(column1,' ','.') ))B(S)
```

**Returns**

```
column1 column2         column3
05      MODE-PARTNER    MIC Z(7)9
08      MODE-FLERS01    MIC X
```

Comment: Clever! I like it.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the grin.  We can only hope the actual data holds true

Comment: Yeah it doesn't cope very well with multiple spaces as OP has shown.

Comment: @John No, when I apply the query on whole table, result set coming wrong and showing NULL

Comment: @RakeshMishra I suspect more than 4 spaces.  ParseName() can only consume a max of 4 items

Comment: @RakeshMishra One option is to clean-up/reduce the number of spaces via nested replace ...  Cross Apply ( values ( replace(replace(replace(replace(column1,'    ',' '),'   ',' '),'  ',' '),' ','.') ))B(S)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the examples provided are indicative, just find and split on the spaces.

```
select
  -- Split out the first section
  substring(x.col1,1,FirstSpace-1) Column1
  -- Split out the second section
  , substring(SecondString, 1, SecondSpace-1) Column2
  -- Split out the third section
  , ltrim(substring(SecondString,SecondSpace,len(SecondString))) Column3
from (values ('05 MODE-PARTNER      MIC Z(7)9'), ('08 MODE-FLERS01      MIC X')) x (col1)
-- Find the first space
cross apply (values (charindex(' ', x.col1))) a (FirstSpace)
-- Remove the first section + spaces
cross apply (values (ltrim(substring(x.col1,FirstSpace+1,len(x.col1))))) b (SecondString)
-- Find the second space
cross apply (values (charindex(' ', SecondString))) z (SecondSpace)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for the example given:

```
declare
    @t table (Fld varchar (1000))

insert into @t
values
('05 MODE-PARTNER      MIC Z(7)9'),
('08 MODE-FLERS01      MIC X')

select LEFT(Fld, charindex(' ', Fld) - 1) column1
    , trim(SUBSTRING(Fld, charindex(' ', Fld)+1, len(Fld) - CHARINDEX(' ', reverse(Fld)) - charindex(' ', Fld)-3)) column2
    , REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(Fld), charindex(' ', reverse(Fld)) +3)) column3
from @t
```

Output:

```
column1 column2 column3
05  MODE-PARTNER    MIC Z(7)9
08  MODE-FLERS01    MIC X
```

Comment: @Dale Thanks Dale but the table columns contains other alphanumeric texts adnd when I try to run on whole table I got the error: "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: @RakeshMishra then you need to ensure your question contains/explains all the possibilities i.e. contains a [mre] for the exact problem you want to solve. And it shouldn't be too hard to adapt one of these solutions to your actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution. It will handle unknown number of spaces between any token.

The **col1** and **col2** columns retrieval is trivial, but the **col3** retrieval is more interesting.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, column1 VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('05 MODE-PARTNER     MIC Z(7)9'),
('08   MODE-FLERS01   MIC X');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
    , TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(column1 COLLATE Czech_BIN2, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
       .query('<root>{for $x in /root/r[text()] return $x}</root>') AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS col1
    , c.value('(r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS col2
    , c.query('data(r[position() gt 2])').value('. cast as xs:token?', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS col3
FROM rs 
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
| ID | col1 |     col2     |   col3    |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 |   05 | MODE-PARTNER | MIC Z(7)9 |
|  2 |   08 | MODE-FLERS01 | MIC X     |
+----+------+--------------+-----------+
```